# SQL query wont return newly added row after hitting the back button despite the row being added in the database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a flask app that has a registration form that `POST` data to a view `registration.py` where the data is added to an SQLite database. Every time a registration happens, a new row is inserted in the database.

**What is expected to happen:**

After submitting the form, if the user hits the back button in the browser and tries to submit the form again, the code below is supposed to

1. `try` to check if the email exists
2. If `exception` (email doesn't exist) insert the data

**The issue:**

When a user hits the back button and submits the form again, the code in the `try` block doesn't recognize the previously (before hitting the back button) added row. The select query fails.

**And even weirder thing:**

However, when I just print out all the rows in the database just before the `try` block, that shows the `email` that's just added. The select query doesn't see it though.

**`Registration.py` issue block**:

```py
    db = get_db()

    # Dumping to log to check if the db actually has the row
    cur_e = db.execute('SELECT user_id, user_email FROM cld_user')
    ie = cur_e.fetchall()
    for i in ie:
        print "ID: {} | Email: {}".format(i[0], i[1])
    print "end of ID dump" 
    print user_email
    # The above code does print out the row (even after hitting the back button)

    try:
        # This block however, fails when user submits the form after hitting the back button
        print "Trying"
        cur_ps = db.execute('SELECT user_id, user_uid FROM cld_user \
            WHERE user_email = ?', [user_email])
        user_id = cur_ps.fetchone()[0]
        user_uid = cur_ps.fetchone()[1]
        print "Row exists"
        flash(user_id, "success")

    except Exception:
        print "Exception"
        cur_p = db.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO cld_user \
            (user_uid, user_name, user_email, user_contact) \
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [user_uid, user_name, 
            user_email, user_contact])
        user_id = cur_p.lastrowid
        print "No row exists"
        flash(user_id, "success")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try` block *always* fails. It fails  at this line `user_uid = cur_ps.fetchone()[0]` if the query returns no rows. It fails at this line `user_uid = cur_ps.fetchone()[1]` if the query returns one row.

`fetchone`  returns one row at a time. This line `user_id = cur_ps.fetchone()[0]` is looking for element 0 in the list returned by `fetchone`. If there are no rows with matching user_email, it fails with "None type object not subscriptable" and therefore executes the `except` block

If a row *is* returned, control moves to this line `user_uid = cur_ps.fetchone()[1]`. If the query returned 2 or more rows, this line will be successful. If it only returned 1 row, the line will fail because the result of `fetchone` is None, and it will give "None type object is not subscriptable".

On possible correction: set a variable to the result of `fetchone`, eg `row = cur_ps.fetchone()`, and then set the other variables to `row[0]` and `row[1]` respectively.

Comment: I understand. But my question is more about why the query returns no rows, while it the query before the try blocks does print out the row. For example, when I print out all the rows, one of the rows have the email `xyz@example.com`. But when the query inside the `try` block tries to run the query for that email, it returns no rows.

Comment: it is the _second_ `fetchone` in the `try` block that returns no rows. See edited answer for more detailed description.

Comment: You are right. I messed up the fetch. The code works. Thanks.